# Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.String'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

I have a new Kotlin project in Eclipse (I installed the kotlin plugin).
However this code:

```
   val a: Int = 10000
   println("Your Int Value is "+a);
```

causes this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.String'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies.
```

What is the source of this error? How can I fix it?

**I have seen the other posts on stackoverflow but they all talk about intellij and not Eclipse.**

Comment: Probably your project structure does not specify the sdk correctly, go to file->project structure->edit sdk

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got this error while using kotlin in eclipse. In my system, JDK was not installed previously. I installed JDK 15 in the PC and set the path in kotlin plugin settings in eclipse (path: Window -> preferences -> Kotlin -> Compiler -> JDK Home)

Comment: IntelliJ user here. Had the same error with the same solution. Doesn't matter what your IDE is, this is a JDK compilation error :) Hope this helps folks using IntelliJ IDEA, Android Studio and Netbeans too.

Answer (score 17):

IntelliJ user here.

In my case, my project settings were (somehow) changed to reference a Java SDK at a path that doesn't exist on my system (hence the inability to find various Java classes).

I fixed this by:

1. Opening the project/module settings through `File -> Project Structure`
2. In the `Project Structure` dialog, find the `Platform Settings` section and click on `SDKs`.
3. For each JDK entry, either remove or fix the entries that don't show any content in the `Classpath` tab.

Comment: This worked for me, the best bet is choosing one of the SDK's from the detected JDK's section

Answer (score 7):

For me fix was by deleting "project"/.idea/misc.xml file