# Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.Boolean'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: java, kotlin

I tried making a function in Kotlin that would ask the user for an item and then add it to the mutableList. The function would ask if the user wants to quit, if true the while loop would be exited and the function would return the mutableList. If false, the function would keep asking the user to input an item until the user is ready to quit. But I ran into an issue while trying to do that.

```
fun addItem(): MutableList<String>{
    var myList = mutableListOf<String>()
    // start a loop to ask the user what items to put in the list
    var quit: Boolean = false

    while(!quit){
        println("Add an item to the list: ")
        var item = readln()
        myList.add(item)

        println("Was that the last item?(true or false")
        var choice = readln()
        quit = if(choice.lowercase() == "true") true else false
    }

    return myList
}
```

I kept getting errors like

'Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.Boolean'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies' when I set the condition for the while loop

AND

'Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.String'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies' when I tried to change the 'choice' variable to lowercase

I'm using openJDK21.0.2 on intelliJ by the way

Comment: Are these build errors, or IDE errors?

Comment: I believe that it is an IDE error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.String'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64527844/cannot-access-java-io-serializable-which-is-a-supertype-of-kotlin-string-ch)

Comment: It actually did, the issue has been resolved. Thank you